# Regression problem on normal distribution data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-science

I have data that resembles students' grade which is normal distribution from 50 to 100 with mean of 80. I would like to do regression to predict this. In order to do regression analysis, because my data is imbalanced (as it has normal distribution), will it be a problem? Or it doesn't matter? Thanks!

Comment: What is your preferred statistics software or programming language?

Comment: I use python. Anyway I am doing text regression to predict this. I might be comparing the results between regression and neural networks.

Comment: Is the maximum possible value equal to 100? If so, the "truncated normal" distribution  might be of interest, the scipy.stats documentation for "truncnorm" is at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html